# ZFS Diff - diff delegated permission is needed

Tags: permissions, zfs, diff

When running `zfs diff` today as non-root, I got an error:

```
Unable to obtain diffs: 
   The sys_mount privilege or diff delegated permission is needed
   to execute the diff ioctl
```

Searching `diff delegated permission` in google did not give any results.

What is diff delegated permission and how do you get around this block to allow non-root users to run `zfs diff`.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is resolved by granting `diff` permission in `ZFS` to the user in question by issuing the following command:

```
sudo zfs allow <user> diff <zpool>/<dataset>
```

eg: To grant diff permission to `jblogs` on dataset `rpool/USERDATA`:

```
sudo zfs allow jblogs diff rpool/USERDATA
```